# FFmpeg command for filename prefix

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to use FFmpeg but I'm lazy to write the full file name. How do I make it automatic?

Example filename:

```
2022 lecture documentation .mp4
```

How do I get the filename prefix to work?

Using this command didn't work for me:

```
ffmpeg -i "2022*.mp4"
```

Comment: You can also remove the quotes around the filename like so `ffmpeg -i 2022*.mp4` and let the shell expand it for you ... but, even then `ffmpeg` might work on the first filename passed to it and then exit afterwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way(*with `find`*) would be:

```
find -type f -name "2022*" -exec ffmpeg -i {} \;
```

And another way(*with a `for` loop*) would be:

```
for f in 2022*; do ffmpeg -i "$f"; done
```